# No se copian los archivos con PHP7

Tags: jquery, php7

Estoy realizando un módulo que explica diferentes políticas de una empresa. Me solicitaron junto con esto que se puedan tanto subir, como descargar archivos. Para ello, tengo una sección que da la opción de subir y así mismo, la opción de observar los demás (que no aparecerá en el código).

Lo estoy intentando de esta forma:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#subir_archivo", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  var form = $('#archivos_energia')[0];
  var formData = new FormData(form);

  if (confirm("¿Desea subir este archivo?")) {

    $.ajax({

      method: "POST",
      url: "archivos.php",
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {

        alert(data);

      }

    });

  }

});
```

```html
<div class="info">

  <img src="imagenes/POLITICAAM.jpg">

  <div class="archivos_derecha">

    <form action="" method="POST" id="archivos_energia">

      <input type="file" name="archivo_energia" id="subir_archivo">

    </form>

    <label for="subir_archivo"><div class="cajas_archivos subir">
     
     Subir archivos...

    </div></label>

  </div>

</div>
```

Y así lo recibo en php7:

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$directorio='archivos';

if(!file_exists($directorio)){

    mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");    

}else{

    $nombre=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['name']; //este es el nombre del archivo que acabas de subir
    $temporal=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['tmp_name'];//este es donde esta almacenado el archivo que acabas de subir.
    $error=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['error']; //este almacena el codigo de error que resultaría en la subida.

$ruta=$directorio . "/" . $nombre;

    if (file_exists($ruta)){

        $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta);

        if ($resultado){

            echo "El archivo ha sido movido exitosamente.";

        } else {

            echo "Ha ocurrido un error al mover el archivo.";

        }

    } else {

        echo "Este archivo ya existe.";

    }


}

?>
```

Se supone que si la variable `$resultado` es verdadera, ahí la subo a la base de datos (aún no he hecho esa línea, debido a que necesito resolver el problema  a continuación). El problema es que testeando la recepción del archivo, no me aparece ni el nombre original, ni el temporal y el error es el número 4, que, según documentación de php7 indica que ningún archivo fue seleccionado. ¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo lo podría corregir?

Además, `if (file_exists($ruta))` en esta ruta no entra, a pesar de que el archivo realmente no existe.

Comment: A tu formulario le falta el `enctype`, tienes que ponerlo así: **`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" id="archivos_energia">`** [Está explicado claramente en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php):  *Asegúrese de que el formulario de subida de ficheros tiene el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` o de lo contrario la subida de ficheros no funcionará.* Todos los formularios que envían archivos deben llevar ese atributo. Pónselo  y nos cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Pude ser por que no se esta enviando bien el archivo desde ajax
intenta cambiando el FormData

Ejemplo:

```
$(document).on("change", "#subir_archivo", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("archivos_energia"));

  if (confirm("¿Desea subir este archivo?")) {

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "archivos.php",
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

la condición `if (file_exists($ruta))` esta de mas  ya que en este parte aun no existe el archivo por lo que nunca entrara

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$ruta='archivos';
if(!file_exists($directorio)){
    if(!mkdir($directorio, 0777)){
      $ruta=""; 
      echo "No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n"; 
    }  
}
if($ruta){
    $nombre=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['name']; //este es el nombre del archivo que acabas de subir
    $temporal=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['tmp_name'];//este es donde esta almacenado el archivo que acabas de subir.
    $error=$_FILES['archivo_energia']['error']; //este almacena el codigo de error que resultaría en la subida.
    $ruta=$ruta . "/" . $nombre;

    if (@move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta)){
        echo "El archivo ha sido movido exitosamente.";
    } else {
        echo "Ha ocurrido un error al mover el archivo.";
    } 
}
```

revisa si la ruta donde intentas crear el directorio archivos tiene permisos de escritura

Comment: No. Aún me sigue apareciendo el error 4.

Comment: $ruta donde la formas?

Comment: Había olvidado subirlo. Ya edité la pregunta con la definición de la variable $ruta.